# How to open front camera as default camera in Android 6

Tags: android, android-camera

I have tried this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,AppConstant.URI_IMAGE_CAPTURED);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
```

This code is working with below the android 6. 
Actually I am using this code to open the front camera which is working fine in below Marshmallow.

Comment: That extra is not in the documentation AFAIK. How are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

This extra was intended for tests only. Currently it's not used anymore according to Camera2 source code.